# cakephp - strange issue with routing

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have my app set up to go to Books index page

Here is my address

```
http://myapp.loc/
```

Here is router

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'books', 'action' => 'index'));
```

When I go to `http://myapp.loc/`, the page loads up just fine. But when I click a link within that page that is suppose to link to `http://myapp.loc/books/index`, it doesn't work.

The web developer tools show

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://myapp.loc/books/index
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

I tried adding a statement in books controller under index action

```
die("here is my breakpoint");
```

I see this when the app loads. But if I take it out and let the app load and then click on the link thats basically the same thing, it doesnt even hit that part of the code.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Router**

```
<?php

/**
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to controller called 'Pages',
 * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
 * to use (in this case, /app/View/Pages/home.ctp)...
 */
    //Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'books', 'action' => 'index'));
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's urls.
 */
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
    CakePlugin::routes();


    Router::mapResources('books', array('id'=>'[0-9A-Za-z]'));
    Router::parseExtensions('json');
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Comment: Sounds (very obviously) like you don't have mod rewrite enabled.

Comment: thats not true....I have mod rewrite enabled...Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.15 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y

mod_rewrite Module Available

Comment: If the url `/` is a CakePHP page, and the url `/asdf` is anything other than a `AsdfController not found` error - the problem is mod rewrite. Check [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html) - the problem is probably omitting `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: I just did a fresh installation of a fresh cakephp copy and that works fine. Which tells me that it is not mod rewrite issue. The issue is somewhere with that specific code base I guess!

Comment: How are you creating that link? With `$this->Html->url()` ? Can you add that piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add second line like

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'books', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/books/*', array('controller' => 'books', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

Check [Manual Here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)

Comment: @Autolycus have you checked my answer?